# Sorting specific parts of rows in R?

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have this matrix with a range of values. I am planning on plotting columns 2 to 6 against the values in column 1. I have seen that it is possible to sort columns of data. How would I sort the data in each row in size order but ignore the data in column 1? E.g The first row would look like

```
          [,1]       [,2]         [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
     [1,]   1      0.05091557  0.05777423 0.07875043  0.08011981  0.09525210
```

Is there anything I should be weary of when sorting matrices this way?

```
      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
 [1,]    1 0.05091557 0.07875043 0.08011981 0.09525210 0.05777423
 [2,]    2 0.01124827 0.11040450 0.15189661 0.17496065 0.05869832
 [3,]    3 0.10205376 0.04264597 0.03424936 0.29083599 0.08650822
 [4,]    4 0.12625884 0.02630636 0.08814499 0.06744327 0.04713059
 [5,]    5 0.02588615 0.31805945 0.09965736 0.11084963 0.08008907
 [6,]    6 0.03488529 0.03275217 0.10867476 0.02974519 0.16357899
 [7,]    7 0.07651835 0.04900895 0.17309055 0.13379696 0.11079284
 [8,]    8 0.04576330 0.04437211 0.14715493 0.17329859 0.19364271
 [9,]    9 0.01288462 0.27600904 0.08185839 0.11899927 0.03254210
[10,]   10 0.05267915 0.10229029 0.03192866 0.01621034 0.16809146
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. As you are working with a matrix, you can use `apply()`. In this function you need to set a range in the matrix. In your case it would be from column two to the last column you have. As the output is transposed you can use `t()` to give the original form as in the initial matrix and then combine with the first column using `cbind()`. Here the code:

```
#Code
mat2 <- cbind(mat[,1],t(apply(mat[,2:6],1,function(x) sort(x))))
```

Output:

```
mat2
      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
 [1,]    1 0.05091557 0.05777423 0.07875043 0.08011981 0.0952521
 [2,]    2 0.01124827 0.05869832 0.11040450 0.15189661 0.1749606
 [3,]    3 0.03424936 0.04264597 0.08650822 0.10205376 0.2908360
 [4,]    4 0.02630636 0.04713059 0.06744327 0.08814499 0.1262588
 [5,]    5 0.02588615 0.08008907 0.09965736 0.11084963 0.3180595
 [6,]    6 0.02974519 0.03275217 0.03488529 0.10867476 0.1635790
 [7,]    7 0.04900895 0.07651835 0.11079284 0.13379696 0.1730906
 [8,]    8 0.04437211 0.04576330 0.14715493 0.17329859 0.1936427
 [9,]    9 0.01288462 0.03254210 0.08185839 0.11899927 0.2760090
[10,]   10 0.01621034 0.03192866 0.05267915 0.10229029 0.1680915
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
mat <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0.05091557, 0.01124827, 
0.10205376, 0.12625884, 0.02588615, 0.03488529, 0.07651835, 0.0457633, 
0.01288462, 0.05267915, 0.07875043, 0.1104045, 0.04264597, 0.02630636, 
0.31805945, 0.03275217, 0.04900895, 0.04437211, 0.27600904, 0.10229029, 
0.08011981, 0.15189661, 0.03424936, 0.08814499, 0.09965736, 0.10867476, 
0.17309055, 0.14715493, 0.08185839, 0.03192866, 0.0952521, 0.17496065, 
0.29083599, 0.06744327, 0.11084963, 0.02974519, 0.13379696, 0.17329859, 
0.11899927, 0.01621034, 0.05777423, 0.05869832, 0.08650822, 0.04713059, 
0.08008907, 0.16357899, 0.11079284, 0.19364271, 0.0325421, 0.16809146
), .Dim = c(10L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```